# API call with name/value in url vs querystring?

Tags: restsharp

im trying to convert the call to the `FORVO api (forvo.com)` from a hardcoded url string to assigning the request parameters one by one to a `ForvoRequestClass's` properties that i created in C# via `.AddParameter method`...but when the request is made...it turns it into querystring format like this:

```
http://apifree.forvo.com/?key=[mykeygoeshere]&language=en&format=json&limit=1&order=rate-desc&sex=f&type=word&word=APPLE}
```

instead of like this:

```
http://apifree.forvo.com/key/[mykeygoeshere]/language/en/format=json/limit/1/order/rate-desc/sex/f/type/word/word/APPLE
```

i have tried various ways to call it using RestSharp...to no avail...any ideas...??

Answer (score 1):

Ok...i believe i found the answer. On the github repo for RestSharp (  [1]: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest) I found the following helpful section:

**UrlSegment**

> Unlike GetOrPost, this ParameterType replaces placeholder values in
>   the RequestUrl:
>
> ```
> var rq = new RestRequest("health/{entity}/status");
> rq.AddParameter("entity", "s2", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
> ```
>
> When the request executes, RestSharp will try to match any
>   {placeholder} with a parameter of that name (without the {}) and
>   replace it with the value.
>
> So the above code results in “health/s2/status” being the Url.

So with this info, I constructed my url string with placeholders for each of the parameters for Forvo like this:

/key/{key}/format/{format}/action/{action}/language/{language}/sex/{sex}/order/{order}/limit/{limit}/type/{type}/word/{word}

My final code to then do the substitution was this:

```
IRestClient client = new RestClient(soundRequest.SiteUrlValue);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.ApiKeyName, soundRequest.ApiKeyValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.ActionName, soundRequest.ActionValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.LanguageName, soundRequest.LanguageValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.FormatName, soundRequest.FormatValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.SexName, soundRequest.SexValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.OrderName, soundRequest.OrderValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.LimitName, soundRequest.LimitValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.TypeName, soundRequest.TypeValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter(soundRequest.WordName, soundRequest.WordValue, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```